# settig left of 'absolute' element to 50% of its direct parent

Tags: css

I have an img within a span, the img is position:absolute, I want to set the left og the img to 50% of the span but since it changes left according to page not span.

Comment: Can you post a working example of your code? In the meantime, try using a div instead of a span.

Answer (score 1):

Give `position:relative` to your `span` like this:

```
span{
 position:relative;
 display:block;
}
```

Read this article for more http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/